# Is there a way to throttle/rate limit messages sent through Azure Web PubSub?

Tags: azure, security, throttling, rate-limiting, azure-web-pubsub

We would like to use Azure Web PubSub to enable browser clients to exchange messages. Ideally, both clients would get a token from a backend service (e.g. serverless function) that gives them permission to join and send messages to a certain group on PubSub, and clients would send and receives messages to and from this group (using `json.webpubsub.azure.v1 subprotocol`).

Our concern is what stops a client from sending an unlimited number of messages, thereby potentially increasing our costs indefinitely (since PubSub charges per message count)? Is there a way to apply rate limiting on an account level basis, so that someone connected from a certain client account can not send more than X messages per minute?

Or is PubSub not meant to be used in use cases from the frontend, but only internally where we control the messages sent?

Thanks!

Comment: [Azure web pubsub Throttling limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/588673/azure-web-pubsub-throttling-limit.html)